# Anyone used SpecFlow with xUnit 2.0 successfully?

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, xunit

The current version of SpecFlow.Xunit is not compatible with xUnit 2.0.

I cannot rollback to xUnit 1.9.0 as all other unit tests are written for xUnit 2.0.  The current verions of SpecFlow.Xunit uses IUseFixture, which is obsolete in xUnit 2.0   .

So I would like to ask if anyone is using SpecFlow.Xunit with xUnit 2.0? How you do it ?

Comment: There's not much we can do for you here. You can follow the issue on GitHub https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/419

Comment: Thank you. I followed the link and install xUnit 1.9.2 and then install SpecFlow.xUnit.  . Now it works so far.

Answer (score 8):

I followed the link CoderDennis suggested. https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/419

Basically, I installed xUnit 1.9.2 and then install SpecFlow.xUnit after. Now, the project can be built without error so far.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Sam! Extending your response, I had to completely remove xUnit, SpecFlow.xUnit and Specflow, and then ran: Install-Package xunit -Version 1.9.2, Install-Package xunit.extensions -Version 1.9.2 and Install-Package specflow.xUnit. Then all worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

The SpecFlow.xUnit NuGet package now has a [pre-release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.xUnit/2.0.0-preview20151221-10) version available with support for xUnit 2.0.